# HTML complex form layout using DIV's

Tags: html, css

I need to make multi-column form layout, where each row can have different count of fields, like this:

[image]

First time I used table and `td`'s `colspan` attribute for creating layout.  But I read that laying out using tables is not good idea, so I want to improve my code to use  `div`'s.

So can anybody give me good example of how to make layout like above according to best practices? The most problem to me is that width of columns is different.

Thanks.

Comment: That's clearly then, NOT a two column layout. What you have is a 5 row layout with each row having it's own 2 column (except for the 100% row) layout.

Comment: And because this is a form, use form elements like `fieldset`, `label` and `legend` tags.

Comment: This Smamatti's version but updated: http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/H4Nf9/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't kill me for not writing 100% valid `input` fields and not a clear layout with margins etc.

**Sample**

http://jsfiddle.net/hpmJ7/4/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="w50">
        <span class="label">Name</span>
        <input type="text" value="Test" />
    </div>
    <div class="w50">
        <span class="label">Surname</span>
        <input type="text" value="Test" />
    </div>

    <div class="w100">
        <span class="label">Contact</span>
        <input type="text" value="Test" />
    </div>

    <div class="w50">
        <span class="label">Age</span>
        <input type="text" value="Test" />
    </div>
    <div class="w50">
        <span class="label">Email</span>
        <input type="text" value="Test" />
    </div>

    <div class="w70">
        <span class="label">Phone</span>
        <input type="text" value="Test" />
    </div>
    <div class="w30">
        <span class="label">Time</span>
        <input type="text" value="Test" />
    </div>

    <div class="w50">
        <span class="label">Age</span>
        <input type="text" value="Test" />
    </div>
    <div class="w50">
        <span class="label">Email</span>
        <input type="text" value="Test" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}
.label {
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.w30, .w50, .w70, .w100 {
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.w30{
    width: 30%;
}
.w50{
    width: 50%;
}
.w70{
    width: 70%;
}
.w100{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but `.w100` don't work as excepted in the link you provided.

Comment: @MyTitle Of course it does. The width of the column is 100%. The input field is just not as wide as you expect it to be. This is dirtyly done with `size`, but check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/hpmJ7/3/

Comment: Hmm. but at least for me it works incorrectly... [The screenshot](http://s23.postimg.org/87vloyhiz/Edit_fiddle_JSFiddle.png)

Comment: @MyTitle Well, that is because on your screen the width of the elements don't fit in the given width 30%. Try it with smaller width for the labels. Remember this is only a sample and you have to do the tuning yourself. -- http://jsfiddle.net/hpmJ7/4/

Comment: @MyTitle Have you tried and understood what I stated in my last comment here? I just saw you added a bouty to this question. IMO you could save the rep and use it on other questions. At least specify what is missing in the sample 4: http://jsfiddle.net/hpmJ7/4/

Comment: @MyTitle Smamatti's way is probably the way I would do it. I started a fiddle that was a bit more explicit than this: http://jsfiddle.net/qJMvL/ There's nothing wrong with providing some more CSS definitions than you think you'd need, especially if you want to control the layout.

Comment: Hey - anyone give tips on how to make the label more flexible with this layout. Any reason to not use HTML label elements instead of a span with class?  1) Right alight the labels - 2) allow more flexibility of the label growth in a change of language (English to German for example)?

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is to come up with some sort of grid system. In my example, I've put together a 5% based grid system. You can see a basic example of some of your exact pieces [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJMvL/).

```
#container { font-size: 12px; width: 700px; }

.row { float: left; margin: 5px 0; width: 100%; }

.w10 { width: 10%; }
.w15 { width: 15%; }
.w20 { width: 20%; }
.w25 { width: 25%; }
.w30 { width: 30%; }
.w35 { width: 35%; }
.w40 { width: 40%; }
.w50 { width: 50%; }
.w60 { width: 60%; }
.w70 { width: 70%; }
.w80 { width: 80%; }
.w90 { width: 90%; }
.w100 { width: 100%; }

.item { box-sizing: border-box; float: left; }

input, select, option { margin: 0; }
```

And I've placed the items into rows to provide for a clean, grid-like look.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item w15">/* Entity Name</div>
        <div class="item w35">Maricopa County Community College District</div>
        <div class="item w50">*Domain: USPF, SLG, Special Districts, Community College</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item w15">/* Doctype</div>
        <div class="item w10">NLP?</div>
        <div class="item w20">Filename/Keywords</div>
        <div class="item w20">*Source Frequency</div>
        <div class="item w35">
            <input type="radio" name="freq" checked="checked" />
            <label>Daily</label>
            <input type="radio" name="freq" />
            <label>Weekly</label>
            <input type="radio" name="freq" />
            <label>Monthly</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item w15">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <label>Audit</label>
        </div>
        <div class="item w10">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item w20">
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item w20">*Every</div>
        <div class="item w15">
            <input type="text" class="w20" value="1"/>
            <label>Days</label>
        </div>
        <div class="item w20">
            <select>
                <option value="utc-6">UTC -6</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, a specific structure is what you're after, and a grid-like system placed in rows is a great way to do that.

Comment: Whoop you wweretalking about this to me haha lucky rat

Answer (score 2):

**Tables are not that bad.**

The reason of why `tables` are not recomended for layout is that the table is loaded(content of it is shown) only when everything in the table has loaded in the page. But divs show their contents as soon as they are loaded.

Now in you case your form looks fairly complex to me and I think it is not desirable to show partial contents of this form while page is still loading. You definitly want to show all the fields of your form at the same time.

Also, when you want to represent tabular data (which I think applies to your case) then it is recomended to use tables.

So I would suggest(I may be wrong, please somebody correct me if I am) using table for this form of yours. 
Also one more benefit that tables provide is you don't have to worry too much about the alignment of your contents.

Comment: I agree with you. People start using divs and then they create classes named "row" and "column" without feeling guilty? Come on. You are reinventing the wheel with different tags. The problem with tables is that the form is not really a table. So you are using markup for something that it is not declared for. Moreover screen-reading devices will interpret your form as a table and blind people will have trouble using your forms. But to me both solutions (DIVs and Tables) are dirty. They simply look all wrong. HTML needs to be extended with tags especially designed for form layouting.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically create multiple css classes which will depict all those widths you want to depict. It will not be strictly flexible columns, but more like flexible rows, you will have to think in terms of rows instead of columns.

so for each row you would attach specific width classes

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left width-50"></div>
    <div class="right width-50"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="left width-70"></div>
    <div class="right width-30"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="left width-100"></div>
</div>
....
....
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="contactForm.css"></link>
</head>
<body>

<div id="contactform">


    <div id="first">
        <div id="name">
            <div id="description">Name</div> 
            <input type="text" name="textName">
        </div> 
        <div id="surname">
            <div id="description"> Surname</div> 
            <input type="text" name="textSurname"> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="second">
        <div id="contact"><div id="description">Contact</div> <input type="text" name="textContact"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="third">
        <div id="age">
            <div id="description">Age</div> 
            <input type="text" name="textAge">
        </div> 
        <div id="e-mail">
            <div id="description">E-mail</div> 
            <input type="email" name="textEmail">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="fourth">
        <div id="phone">
            <div id="description">Phone</div> 
            <input type="text" name="textPhone">
        </div> 
        <div id="time">
            <div id="description">Time</div> 
            <input type="date" name="textTime">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#contactform {width:500px; height:500px;}

#contactform div {float:left; padding-top:5px;}
#first, #second, #third, #fourth {width:100%;} 

#first #description {width:30%;}
#name, #surname {width:50%;}
#surname #description {margin-left:11px;}
#first input {width:65%;}

#second #description {width:15%;}
#contact {width:100%;}
#second input {width:85%;}

#third #description {width:30%;}
#age, #e-mail {width:50%;}
#e-mail #description {margin-left:11px;}
#third input {width:65%;}

#fourth #description {width:30%;}
#phone, #time {width:50%;}
#time #description {margin-left:11px;}
#fourth input {width:65%;}
```

**Output**

[image]

HTH.

Comment: I just noticed that in the time input I forgot to change the width. However, I do prefer how it looks like when not using different widths. IMHO looks more consistent.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it is not good idea to create so many CSS classes.. I'll try to improve your solution

Comment: I agree, it can be improved :)